# Sci fi movie 80's child sized killer robot, wasteland, apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, robots

I'm trying to find a film I saw on VHS rental in the 80's. It had a child sized robot that was a guardian of several humans, escorting them across a apocalyptic wasteland.  The robot spoke and was child-like, but when switched into killer mode it would kill anyone and become a threat to even those it protected.  I've had no luck looking for it IMDb and sci-fi film sites. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Was the robot a guardian of the humans or their ward?

Comment: When in child mode it was their ward. When in killer mode it was their guardian

Answer (score 4):

Sounds vaguely similar to **[Screamers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114367/)** - a 1995 film which was based on the Phillip K. Dick short story "[Second Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Variety)"

A couple of key fits specifically are wasteland travel and a defensive killer robot child. The date given is inconsistent with the film, however, the short story was written in the 50's so it's possible there might have been a different, earlier adaptation (although I can't find any reference to one other than Screamers)

Comment: It's definitely not screamers.

Comment: it definitely sounds like a rip-off of Second Variety then :)

Answer (score 2):

"Starship"(1984)?

Also known as "Lorca and the Outlaws" and "2084", it has the 'child-like' android escorting people across an apocalyptic wasteland.

Here is a plot synopsis from Wikipedia:

"On the remote mining planet Ordessa, the management uses killer military police androids to crack down on workers upset with the terrible conditions. Lorca (John Tarrant) and his mother Abbie (Donogh Rees) led the human underground resistance movement until Abbie was killed by androids. Now, Lorca and Suzi (Cassandra Webb) battle Captain Jowitt (Ralph Cotterill) and the brutal bounty hunter Danny (Hugh Keays-Byrne), with the help of the friendly android Grid (Deep Roy).[2][3][4]"

I can't find a trailer, but here is the entire movie from Youtube.